# ubuntu is not able to start up with Bluetooth error

Tags: installation, wubi, bluetooth, reboot, log

I used to have dual system on my laptop windows 7 and ubuntu. when I add a SSD to my laptop I decide to install windows8 and ubuntu in my new SSD. I format the old partions, one for windows 7 and one for ubuntu. Installation for windows8 is good and I use **Wubi windows install** to install ubuntu like my old way.

First time when I reboot laptop it is fine, but when I reboot laptop again and trying to enter ubuntu system give me an error message below:

```
[    8.986589] Bluetooth: Can't change to loading configuration err
                                                               [ ok ]
```

after I enter my password, it shows the log below.

```
[   70.771434] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: EvoCh 1 Mthd 0x0080 Data 0x00000000 ( 0x0006 0x05)
[   76.889553] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: EvoCh 1 Mthd 0x0080 Data 0x00000000 ( 0x1006 0x05)
[   95.494879] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Failed to idle channel 1.
[   98.493900] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Failed to idle channel 2.
[  101.500948] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Failed to idle channel 3.
[  110.006986] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup - switching to software fbcon
[  113.921003] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Failed to idle channel 1.
[  116.920051] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Failed to idle channel 2.
[  130.087864] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Failed to idle channel 1.
[  133.086912] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Failed to idle channel 2.
[  146.186745] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Failed to idle channel 1. 
[  149.185795] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Failed to idle channel 2.
[  162.309621] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Failed to idle channel 1.
```

I have no idea what happening. I have try to uninstall wubi, format partion and reinstall ubuntu again (in the windows) but it doesn't work with same error.

I don't know what is wrong, I don't even want use any Bluetooth. Can some one help me?  I post the log picture below: 
[log picture](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/58367953/2013-03-13%2011.58.25.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same, then I found hint to remove word "splash" from grub start command line
from /boot/grub/grub.cfg, try to remove word "splash" from that file (running for example "try ubuntu" from install iso cd) and restart. It should run as usual. It is something with nvidia drivers. I don't know exactly what, but this solution wors for me.